# How do i increase the width of modal window

Tags: html, css

I have created a modal using html , css and JavaScript ( codes of which are included in snippet )

The issue is the parent class ".modal" already has width and height both set to 100% 
Still when the modal window is opened , it leaves some space on both sides

I am also uploading a pic to better show what I am talking about [Pic showing how modal window looks when opened in device](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10MQW8sz6OSPbXeYzU4GtdoEjyMgp1TBB/view?usp=drivesdk)

[ On a side note ,i am aware that if modal window takes full width of page , the functionality of user clicking outside of modal for closing it won't work,. That's fine by me.  There's a "X" icon at top to close the window and that's enough ]

```js
$(function(){

// Get the button that opens the modal
// read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

// All page modals
var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
 btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
    modal.style.display = "block";
 }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
 spans[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
    }
 }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
     for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
     }
    }
}
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 5px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #171B20;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #F0B823;
    float: right;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: -10px;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #171B20;
    color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {
}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20; 
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 200%;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 60%;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.bodytext {
   font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
   display: block;
   padding: 10px 15px;                                                                                                       
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 35%;
 }
}

p {
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#myModal1" class="modal-button">• Click Me</a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">×</span>
            <div class="headertext">
                <p>Modal Header</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
            <div class="bodytext">
                <p>Body Text Comes here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `.modal-content { width: 80%; };` to a higher value, if you want it to be full width then change it to `.modal-content { width: 100%; };` (or `width: 100vw;`)

Comment: Thank you sir.  That fixed it

Answer (score 0):

`.modal-content` `width` needs to be changed to `100%`

```js
$(function(){

// Get the button that opens the modal
// read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

// All page modals
var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
 btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
    modal.style.display = "block";
 }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
 spans[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
    }
 }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
     for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
     }
    }
}
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 5px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #171B20;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #F0B823;
    float: right;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: -10px;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #171B20;
    color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {
}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20; 
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 200%;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 60%;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.bodytext {
   font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
   display: block;
   padding: 10px 15px;                                                                                                       
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 35%;
 }
}

p {
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#myModal1" class="modal-button">• Click Me</a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">×</span>
            <div class="headertext">
                <p>Modal Header</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
            <div class="bodytext">
                <p>Body Text Comes here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```